# Method '-cleanTitle.' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: iphone, uitableview, twitter, rss, warnings

I'm trying to implement an rss feed into my app and I have created a method to clean the title up.

```
- (NSString *)cleanTitle:(NSString *)Title {
return [Title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"twitterfeed: " withString:@""];
}
```

The warning occurs on the `articleTitle` line below:

```
- (void)parseAtom:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

NSString *blogTitle = [rootElement valueForChild:@"title"];                    

NSArray *items = [rootElement elementsForName:@"entry"];
for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

    NSString *articleTitle = [self cleanTitle: [item valueForChild:@"title"]];
```

Do you know how to get rid of this warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `- (NSString *)cleanTitle:(NSString *)Title` is also declared in your header file.

Answer (score 0):

The method's signature must be known before it is used if the two methods are not in the same category or class. If it's the same class but `-cleanTitle:` is in a `(Private)` category or some such, be sure to declare that category prior to your class' implementation (in your .m file) :

```
@interface MyClass (Private)
- (NSString *)cleanTitle: (NSString *)title;
@end
```