# Method '-parseRss:entries.' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: iphone, uitableview, error-handling, rss, warnings

I am coming across a warning in my app as I'm trying to implement an rss feed.

The warning: `Method '-parseRss:entries.' not found (return type defaults to 'id').`
and 
`Method '-parseAtom:entries.' not found (return type defaults to 'id').` are occuring below, on the `self...` line

```
- (void)parseFeed:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

    if ([rootElement.name compare:@"rss"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        [self parseRss:rootElement entries:entries];
    } else if ([rootElement.name compare:@"feed"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        [self parseAtom:rootElement entries:entries];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unsupported root element: %@", rootElement.name);
    }
}
```

I tried putting: `- (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries` and - `(void)parseAtom:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries` in the .h file but it came up with errors.

How can I take out the 2 warnings?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method '-cleanTitle.' not found (return type defaults to 'id').](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573534/method-cleantitle-not-found-return-type-defaults-to-id)

Comment: Actually, *exact* duplicate. You *just* asked this same question for a different method name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of suggestions

- Make absolutely sure that your
  methods in the .h file are exactly as typed in the .m file
- Make sure that the return types for your warning methods are correct
- Try putting your implementation for `parseRSS` and `parseAtom` before your implementation of `parseFeed`

If I'm not mistaken, you're following the tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial) for making an RSS reader.  You'll notice, if you download the full source code at the bottom that Ray doesn't add the method headers in the .h file.  He implements the `parseRSS` and `parseAtom` functions before the `parseFeed` function.

Comment: Putting my implementation for `parseRSS` and `parseAtom` before my implementation of `parseFeed` fixes the warning. Thanks mate.